# How do I link a form in a Django template?

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I'm new to Python and Django so bear with me. I'm trying to include a form section within one base.html class.
This is how I've done it:

Views.py:

```
class WikiForm(forms.Form):
    original = forms.Textarea()
    wikified = forms.Textarea()
    raw_html = forms.Textarea()

def index(request):
    wikiform = WikiForm()
    template = loader.get_template('base.html', wikiform)
    context = RequestContext(request, {})

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Base.html

```
<div class="sub-background">
    {% block content %}
       {{ wikiForm }}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

This has worked, it's only since trying to add in a form section that it fails with this error.

Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT**
This is the full error:

```
> C:\Python27\django-trunk\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
E:\Dropbox\University Project\wikify\Wikify_Project\Wikify_Project\views.py in index
    template = loader.get_template('base.html', wikiform) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python27\django-trunk\django\template\loader.py in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name, dirs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python27\django-trunk\django\template\loader.py in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name) ...
▶ Local vars
```

I can fix this error by not passing in the wikiform into template, but then how do I pass the form into the template to include to render it in the HTML?

Comment: Where do you put `base.html`?

Comment: That is not the error, since the last line says that the template was found, indeed. Please post the full message.

Comment: I've edited the original post, but I'm not sure if I am looking in the right place. I know it's got to do with the way I've tried to add a form.

Comment: Move the html file to `Wikify_Project\templates\Wikify_Project\base.html`

Comment: That is not your actual code, as running that code would give the error `TypeError: get_template() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)` (because `get_template` only takes one parameter). Please be sure you are posting code that actually exhibits the relevant error.

Comment: I've run that code several times, and no error has come up about 2 parameters for template.
The code I've posted does give me that I've pasted in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
template = loader.get_template('base.html', wikiform)
```

According to the development version docs, the structure for this method is this:

```
get_template(template_name[, dirs])
```

For django 1.6 and earlier, the dirs parameter does not exist. If you are not using the dev version of django, that line should give you some kind of error about only allowing one parameter. If you are using the dev version, `wikiform` is not a list of directories, so that would never work.

If you want to pass the form to the template, you need to do this:

```
wikiform = WikiForm()
template = loader.get_template('base.html')
context = RequestContext(request, {'form': wikiform})
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I got something to work but my fix meant that it was complaining about my css and js being sent as plain-text. You've fixed two errors in one. Thank you!!!